# CSS: drop grid rows/items if they won't fit the available height

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In the test page below, I have a grid configured in `<body>` whose height is tied to the browser window size. In one of its columns, there is `aside`, itself with a 1-column, 4-row grid where two fixed-height titles are followed by boxes which are themselves, guess what, also 1-column grids.

The items (grid rows) of such boxes don't have to grow or shrink, I'd be fine with the heights of their contents. The behaviour I am looking for is: if the browser window is not tall enough to show all the items in their natural heights, such inner boxes (class `.asidebox`) should show only as many items as could fit.

This is what I expected to happen if the `.asidebox`es 1) are able to vertically shrink to fit the window without overflowing and 2) are configured with `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, ...)`.

I must have got it wrong. So far I've been able to get *anything but this* with various different settings. The code below for the `asidebox` class has comments on some of these configurations and their effects. I also played with the `grid-template-rows` of the `aside` selector in various combinations, but nothing worked as I expected. Not even you-know-who-or-what was able to help on it.

So... Is there a CSS-only way to drop rows of a grid if they won´t fit in an externally defined height?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        p, h1, h2, h3, h4 {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        body {
            display: grid;
            margin: 0;
            border-bottom: 3px solid purple;
            background-color: #f1e2ad;
            grid-template-columns: 5fr minmax(min-content, 30%);
            grid-template-rows: 99vh;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }

        aside {
            background-color:darkkhaki;
            display: grid;
            /* align-content: start; */
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto minmax(0, 1fr);
        }
        
        .asidebox {
            display: grid;
            min-height: 0;
            
            /* Items will grow, but won't shrink; areas both overflow and overlap. Same
                effect of simply not configuring grid-template-rows:
            grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, min-content);  */

            /* First row initially bigger, will hide behind the rest of the box on resize:
            grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 100%)); */

            /* Items will grow and shrink to 0, but won't be removed: 
            grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 1fr));  */

            /* Might do it but is invalid: 
            grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, clamp(0, min-content, 1fr));  */

            /* Neither are accepted as well:
            grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, auto);
            grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, 1fr);  */

            /* Items won't grow, but will shrink to 0 instead of being dropped:
            grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, min-content)); */

            /* Also invalid:
            grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min-content, 1fr)); 
            grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(1fr, min-content)); */ 
        }

        .asidebox > article {
            border: 2px solid green;
            padding: 2px;
            background-color: yellow;
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="esq"></div>
    <aside id="dir">
        <h2>News</h2>
        <div class="asidebox">
            <article class="news">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</p>
            </article>
            <article class="news">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</p>
            </article>
            <article class="news">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</p>
            </article>
        </div>
    
    
        <h2>Top reporters</h2>
        <div class="asidebox">
            <article class="user">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</p>
            </article>
            <article class="user">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</p>
            </article>
            <article class="user">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</p>
            </article>
            <article class="user">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</p>
            </article>
        </div>
    </aside>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely doable with flexbox. Make the following changes to your code:

1️⃣ On the `body` element, hide all overflow:

```
body {
  ...
  /* overflow-y: hidden; */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

2️⃣ On your `.asidebox` elements, style them as a [flex column](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#aa-flex-direction) rather than grid, allowing items which don’t fit to wrap (into a new column, which overflows and will therefore be hidden):

```
.asidebox {
  /* display: grid; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  ...
}
```

3️⃣ Allow flex items to grow (optional):

```
.asidebox > article {
  ...
  flex: 1;
}
```

Here is a snippet to demonstrate. After running it, make sure to use the **full page** link to properly test the responsiveness.

```css
p, h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid purple;
  background-color: #f1e2ad;
  grid-template-columns: 5fr minmax(min-content, 30%);
  grid-template-rows: 99vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

aside {
  background-color: darkkhaki;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto minmax(0, 1fr);
}

.asidebox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 0;
}

.asidebox > article {
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="esq"></div>
<aside id="dir">
    <h2>News</h2>
    <div class="asidebox">
        <article class="news">
            <h4>Title 1</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</p>
        </article>
        <article class="news">
            <h4>Title 2</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</p>
        </article>
        <article class="news">
            <h4>Title 3</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</p>
        </article>
    </div>


    <h2>Top reporters</h2>
    <div class="asidebox">
        <article class="user">
            <h4>Title 4</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</p>
        </article>
        <article class="user">
            <h4>Title 5</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</p>
        </article>
        <article class="user">
            <h4>Title 6</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</p>
        </article>
        <article class="user">
            <h4>Title 7</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</p>
        </article>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: Hey, Brett, thank you. I tried a Flexbox approach without success and your proposal is really useful and smart. Most of all, the concept of forcing items into a hidden overflow column seemed to be the key, and I was able to get it somehow working with grid as well, by configuring .asidebox with `grid-auto-columns: 0`, `grid-auto-flow: column` and a fixed length for the rows with `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(3rem, 1fr))` . As the question arose from a grid-specific course lesson, I'd rather wait for a grid-based approach, but your reply is already very "acceptable".